# filter map result with duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, map-function

I have a command handler that uses a map with commands assigned from user command folders and a general comm folder. User can add their own commands. the map filters using name inside the file which is also how the call them. How do I make a comparison if there is more than one with the same name? Afaik maps can't do this and fear I have to redo it all.

At first I was trying to assign every user it's own map

```
 client.User1.get(command, argument);
 client.User2.get(command argument);
```

was this actually the right way to do it? I am using a .JSON with enabled command names for initial comparison. Below some of the code, as you ccan probably tell i'm not that experienced.

```
const assignedChannels = client.opts.channels.slice(0);
assignedChannels.unshift('#basiccommands');
const rootForCommands = "./commands";
client.commandCall = new Map();

for (const channelspecificDir of assignedChannels) {

 const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${rootForCommands}/${channelspecificDir}`);

 for (const file of commandFiles) {
     const commandCollection = require(`${rootForCommands}/${channelspecificDir}/${file}`);
     //sets a new item in the collection.
     //Key of map as command name and the value the function to send message and argument true or false
     client.commandCall.set(commandCollection.name, commandCollection);

     const currentProfile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./userProfiles/${channel}.json`, 'utf8'));
     if (!currentProfile.all_commands.includes(commandPre)){
         return console.log("Command does not exist");
     } 
     try {
        client.commandCall.get(commandPre, argU).execute(channel, argU);
     } catch (error) {
         console.log('command broke');
         console.error(error);
     }
```

My prevoious method was to assign user specific folder and general command folder to a map and at the end of each iteration change the name of the map object. But that does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use symbols as keys for maps

```
const map = new Map()
map.set(Symbol(‘the same name’), value1)
map.set(Symbol(‘the same name’), value2)
```

You can use any values for Map’s keys, even objects and functions

```
map.set({}, value3)
map.set({}, value4)
```

In all previous expressions we get different values (links) for Map’s keys.

BTW. Be aware with `const some = require(‘some_file_name’)`.
`require()` caches a value for a file name. So, if your files may be updated during a run time and you need to read these updates you shouldn’t use ‘require()’. It’s good only for importing modules and static values (e.g. configs)

Comment: I have read about that with the require yeah, will have to look into that. Will try the symbols when I get home and let you know. I was thinking that maybe I needed a function constructor that makes map objects. So that I can name each map according to the user it's grabbing the commands for. But haven't found a way to name variables like that. the client[stringLiteralHere] did not work, all it gave was empty maps.

Comment: Why would it be useful to use a `Symbol` that you don't store anywhere as the key in a Map?  Without saving it somewhere else, you could never look it up in the Map by the symbol and thus wouldn't really have any particular use for the Map data structure.  May as well use an `Array` or a `Set` if you're not going to save the key.  Plus, it isn't clear how this suggestion helps solve the OP's actual problem either.

Comment: Also, you can't create a Symbol with `new Symbol(someString)`.  You use `Symbol(someString)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 with `new` it was a typo. Thanks you notice that.

Comment: @jfriend00 you can’t save symbols in databases. But you can compare symbols. TBH there’re not so many cases when we can use symbols. Usually I avoid them and use  other approaches.

Comment: I know you can't save them outside of Javascript.  I'm just saying that there's no point in using one as a key in a `Map` if you don't have the symbol somewhere (in some sort of Javascript data structure or variable) so you could use it to look it up in the `Map`.  If not, then there's no point to using a Map if you don't have the key.